# Remove Buttons From Compact Layout in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, compact-layout

I have a custom object and it has a lookup field to Accounts, Contacts, and Leads. Using recordTypes I have 3 different layouts so that only the relevant lookup is seen on the page layout. The page layout seems to be responding as expected right now, but the compact layout (I believe that's what I'm referring to), not so much.

Now, I am struggling here to understand, 1) why these buttons appear here by default anyways (new contact, new opportunity, etc?), 2) why not just standard new, edit, delete options for the actual record I'm dealing with.

[image]

So can I remove any of these from the view? And can I add more practical ones like "New"?

Comment: @sfdcfox So because the answer is similar the question is considered the same? I see I should have asked about "quick actions" but I wasn't asking how to add a URL button or anything, just how to remove the unnecessary standard ones that were put there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not compact layout.

They are standard quick actions which are added to page layout by default.

You need to remove them from here:
[image]